# How to get Com object from Process?

Tags: python, python-2.7, com

Hi I am new to python programming. I know how to dispatch a com object **(ex: obj = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')**. This will start the application process.

Can anyone explain how to get the Com object from process? I want to get the com object for any process listed in the process list of windows so that I can execute the methods of the retreived com object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not every process listed in the process list is a COM server. In fact, few are. And even if you find a process that is a COM server, and manage to obtain a COM object reference from it - how would you know which methods to "execute"? What problem are you really trying to solve? Your question sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using web cam software and sometimes it hangs. I can kill the process by retrieving the Process ID from process. But I want to learn how to get COM object from process object  ( I am using psutil library) . Also I know the methods of the application from its type library. Please explain if there is any way to do this.

Comment: There is no way, in general, to get a COM object reference from a process, even if that process happens to house a COM server. If you are lucky, the server has registered itself with [the running object table (ROT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684004.aspx), and you can get it from there (before you ask, I have no idea how to do this with Python). Having said that, if the process is hanging - meaning, it doesn't react to user actions - then most likely it won't react to COM calls either.